# Kitten is cuddly, not playful--typical?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

I am fostering a 10 week old kitten, tested negative for feline leukemia (but littermates are positive). He's the sweetest kitten, is very cuddly, walks around the house with me (and that's just after 3 days), always wants to be with me, but doesn't really play. I have the feathers, the balls, the mice, but he's not interested in them.

Is this typical? He seems healthy in other ways (eating, drinking, litter boxing).

Answer (score 6):

**Animals have different personalities.** Some kittens may not be attracted to toys. Not playing with toys alone is not a symptom.

Lethargy itself is an important symptom and a good reason for an early vet visit. However, if he follows you and if he shows a decent activity doing so, as long as he doesn't show any other symptoms, I would not worry about it.

Furthermore, there is a good chance the kitten is very attached to you. Try to be present in his playtime. Drag a string on the ground, or move the toys yourself. Check if he engages with the toys. If this is the case, it means he prefers you over toys.

Comment: Plus some cats are *peculiar* when it comes to toys. Maybe the OP just hasn’t found the “right” kind of toy.

Answer (score -2):

No isn't sound typical. Because your sweety (kitten) is growing elder. he wants to be a usual cat. this time he is making the decision he is continuing with you or going to be a wild cat. I guess that's all.
I have a tip for you.
This time to more take care of him, it will help him to make a decision easily to be with you.

Give him a kiss to me.

Comment: Welcome! Have you noticed that the kitten in the question is only ten weeks old? That is far too young to turn into an adult cat? At that age, a kitten would normally still be with his mother and quite a while away from being a grown cat.

Comment: Yes, I did. this is far too baby kitten to young kitten.